# How do i call ImageList.Images.Clear() from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, imagelist

How do I call ImageList.Images.Clear() from another thread? I tried to do a function like

```
 private delegate void SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue);

    public static void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(SetControlPropertyThreadSafe), new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
        }
        else
        {
            control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
        }
    }
```

but ImageList doesn't have an InvokeRequired or Invoke, plus I don't want to set a property, I just want to call

```
ImageList.Images.Clear()
```

Comment: You need to keep track of your thread contexts. It may seem like a pain now but you will save yourself time in the future to get this right.

Comment: your code has one problem - IF the `Handle` of the control/its parent has not been created THEN `InvokeRequired` will return `false`. Before the first use of your code you MUST make sure that `Handle` has been created on the UI thread otherwise your application will get into strange trouble !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(o => ImageList.Images.Clear(), null);
```

This will asynchronously invoke the delegate on the UI thread. If you need to immediately clear the list replace Post with Send. Of course you also need the reference to the ImageList you want to clear.

Comment: Just out of curiosity because I've never seen it before, but what does => do?

Comment: In this context, you can think of it as an in-line delegate. `o` is the parameter, and the body of the method is `ImageList.Images.Clear()`, so in this case, the parameter `o` isn't used. The type of `o` is determined by [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).

Comment: @Thomas The `SynchronizationContext.Send` method requires a `SendOrPostCallback` delegate with signature `public delegate void SendOrPostCallback(Object state)`. The `state` parameter is used to pass some data to the delegate, I just called that parameter `o` for brevity.

Comment: @BorisB. what about adding image to an ImageList instead of clearing it?

Comment: @Behzad: I guess it should be the same, i.e. `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(o => ImageList.Images.Add(myImage), null);` or something like that.

Comment: @BorisB. I've checked it, but it raises Null exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: @Behzad Try to assert which of the objects is null and then why. If that doesn't work you should probably post a new SO question.